# Ubuntu 18.04.1 DVD Install Disc has corrupt graphics on AMD A8 graphics

Tags: ubuntu, video

After booting Ubuntu 18.04.1 from a DVD (burned the latest ISO) the laptop booted with a corrupt screen (the mouse cursor is clearly visible though).

Is there a function key or hidden option? This is going on an older but very capable AMD A8 8GB RAM 750GB SSD laptop that I'm lending to someone. I don't use Ubuntu so I'm not sure if it's booting to "try before you install" mode or going to an installer.

Is there a hidden option or different approach using the ISO 18.04.1 ISO burned DVD to avoid only seeing the corrupt graphics?[image: Ubuntu 18 Corrupt Installation]

Comment: Do you get the 
graphic menus with the *F6 Other Options*, or tried just adding some of the kernel options ("boot codes")  such as nomodeset or noapic, etc? Probably searching for the  video card or laptop model might read to a solution, guessing not the A8 itself since I've used older Ubuntus & Debians on A8's with no problems (or 18.04 is really different). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Comment: @Xen2050 The system doesn't give any options and just goes through a few screens before ultimately ending up what you see above. I'm out of town for a day though when I'm back tomorrow night I will try the F1 ~ F6 keys immediately after the laptop powers on. I'll try to remember to post the Laptop model too. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I haven't tried a live Ubuntu in a while, but iirc the actual dvd's (or an iso that's dd-"burned" to a usb) uses something like syslinux & displays a splash screen by default, but pressing a key at the right time might show the menu. Unless it's showing you a grub menu first that's editable, multi-boot usb's often do that. Apparently rufus's ISO mode usb might jump straight to the ubuntu + 5 dots loading screen from a video on youtube, not sure if it allows for any options

Comment: @Xen2050 I had to abandon Ubuntu and install a copy of Windows 7. The person I'm lending the laptop for has a brother who kept complaining about closed source ATI drivers...they haven't even existed since circa 2006! Besides the fact that Ubuntu's UX is atrocious I *do* want to see Linux succeed though they clearly need more rigorous testing methodologies.

Comment: Nearly every Linux distro has a few tweaks (sometimes bugs) that need custom settings to iron out, if one doesn't even boot live I move onto another similar one, or another... And new versions (every 6 months for Ubuntu) can introduce new problems. Ubuntu hasn't been #1 on distrowatch.org's rankings for years now, I think when they introduced "Unity" and tons of users said "no thanks". Linux Mint was/is very popular, currently Manjaro seems to be though I haven't tried it, MX Linux is great for me (Like a "regular" desktop, great live, very customizable & stable).

Comment: If the people using the laptop weren't familiar with Ubuntu (or any Linux) already, and didn't want to learn, they probably wouldn't have been very happy anyway.

Comment: @Xen2050 The person I've lent the laptop to said she preferred Ubuntu. I'm sure you're correct about all the various flavors and the bugs and tweaks. Thank you for trying!